# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отправить текст в формате марки Авто(Acura) в поле input через Selenium на Python. Поле input выглядит следующим образом:

Tags: python, selenium

[image: Так выглядит поле куда я собираюсь вставить свою строку]

[image: Сам элемент страницы имеет такой]

Так выглядит поле куда я собираюсь вставить свою строку

Я обращаюсь к нему с таким кодом:

```
driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)
    marka_input = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "select2-search__field")
    marka_input.clear()
    marka_input.send_keys(marka)
    marka_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Но вылезает ошибка вида:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".select2-search__field"}.Сайт, где пытаюсь это сделать - https://rrr.lt/ru
Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с данной проблемой?

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)